# How to pass TimeZone Name from Angular to .NET API?

Tags: .net, angular, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I have an API that accepts the TimeZone name **(America/Denver)** as a string. In the Angular UI application, I am passing the TimeZone name by detecting the browser timeZoneName. But when the API receives the string as `America/Denver` it considers as a route parameter and doesn't work as expected.

So, I am replacing the `/` with `-` in Angular using string.replace() and passing to the API, and converting it back in .NET API.

I think it is a bad practice to modify timeZone names. Can anyone advise on how to pass timeZone names from Angular to .NET API?

Is it possible to pass the offsets from the UI and get timeZone names in API?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to encode the string parameter you are sending to the api.

Do something like:

```
let timeZone  = "America/Denver"

let encodedTimeZone = encodeURIComponent(timeZone);
```

and send the `encodedTimeZone` to the api.
You can log the `encodedTimeZone` to the console to see the encoded string.

Comment: I tried this. But this still modifies the timezone name by encoding. Is that a good practice? Is there a way we can just use the DateTime type in .NET? Is there a way to get timeZoneName using offsets?

Comment: I recommended that because you said in your question that the api takes a string parameter, and yes, it will encode the string you are sending to the api then decode it when it gets to the api action. For offsets, you can check out `DateTimeOffset` [Datetimeoffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.offset?view=net-6.0) and [Timezone info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo?source=recommendations&view=net-6.0) class.